# ASP.NET file compiled, still not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have an asp.net (version 4) website, for which I made a copy of the default.aspx file to test an alternate design. Works perfectly on my dev PC (IIS 7.5 I think) but I get a "Page not found" error on the server.

The really strange thing is that when I wanted to troubleshoot this and renamed the file but forgot to change the `CodeFile="default2.aspx.cs"` in the first line of `default2.aspx`, I got an error saying that it couldn't compile. Which was correct, of course. But when I change that too so that it compiles, it goes back to the page not found error.

So if it can't be compiled, it's there.

If it compiles, it's not there.

What am I missing here?

PS. In the IIS logs I see 404s and sometimes 301s. I checked some explanations of 301 so I'd like to rule out the redirection as a possible solution. I don't redirect anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure where exactly the error was within FriendlyUrls, but getting rid of it solved the issue. So it was working on my dev machine with IIS 7.5, but IIS 6 on my rather old server seems to be incapable of handling FriendlyUrls. I don't really need that, so axed.